# Viewing changes in branch using Xcode Version Editor?

Tags: git, version-control, xcode4.3

I started a project with Git enabled to try out the feature, in the "Master" trunk I added two methods called `feature_ONE` and `feature_TWO` and committed the changes. I then went to the organiser and added a branch to the trunk called **feature_THREE_Branch**. I then switched to this branch and implemented `feature_THREE` before again committing the changes.

In the image below I have switched back to the "Master" trunk and I am trying to view the current **Master** against the **feature_THREE_branch** so I can see what changes were made. My problem is that whatever I do in the version editor I can't seem to see feature_THREE. Should it not be showing on the right hand side under feature_TWO (thats where it is if you switch to the **feature_THREE_Branch**, What am I missing?

[image]

Xcode Version 4.3.2 (4E2002)

Comment: I don't see anything you're missing. You said you committed your changes for Feature 3. Your screenshot shows the local revision. If you click on the jump bar at Local Revision for your Feature 3 branch and choose the commit you made, does the version editor show the code you added?

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your issue; it surely is confusing but I was able to see the differences.  My observations:

- The branch+revision information at the bottom, when clicked, does show the branches but the revisions are fouled up.  For example, under the 'master' branch the commits will show stuff from the 'feature_THREE_Branch.  Then when you select the commit from the 'feature_THREE_Branch' it doesn't get displayed.
- As you show above, when the left has 'master' and the right has 'feature_THREE_Branch' you **can't select** the commit (from the feature_THREE_Branch') and get that to display.
- The center, blackish 'local, base, ...' column shows commits from the left side selected branch.  If you want to see your diff you need to first select 'feature_THREE_Branch' on the left side (bottom) and then on the right side of the blackish column 'scroll' back to the commit from the 'master' branch.
- The only way to get file content to consistently display is by clicking the left or right side of the center, blackish bar.

[Above is not very clear... hard to describe this UI...]